# Flutter error: The return type 'Stream<Class>' isn't a 'Stream<Class>'

Tags: flutter, dart

in my database implementation i have this method:

```
static Stream<User> getUserInformationStream() async{
    var dbClient = await db;
    return dbClient.userDao.getUser();
}
```

which that `getUser()` is:

```
@Query('SELECT * FROM User LIMIT 1')
Stream<User> getUser();
```

in database helper implementation i'm trying to use this method to return `Stream` but i get this error:

> error: The return type 'Stream<User>' isn't a 'Stream<User>', as
>   defined by the method 'getUserInformationStream'.
>   (return_of_invalid_type at [diabetist_pro]
>   lib\database\database_model.dart:36)

my complete database helper class:

**UPDATED**

`DbModel` class into `db_model.dart` file

```
class DbModel {
  static final DbModel _instance = DbModel.internal();

  factory DbModel()=> _instance;

  static AppDatabase _db;

  static Future<AppDatabase> get db async {
    if (_db != null) {
      return _db;
    }
    _db = await initDb();
    return _db;
  }

  DbModel.internal();

  static initDb() async {
    var db = await $FloorAppDatabase.databaseBuilder('diabetist.db').build();
    return db;
  }

  /* work fine */
  static Future<User> getUserInformation() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    return dbClient.userDao.getUserFuture();
  }

  /* not working and i get error */
  static Stream<User> getUserInformationStream() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    return dbClient.userDao.getUser();
  }
}
```

**UPDATED**

and `user_dao.dart` class witch that is another file

```
@dao
abstract class UserDao{
  @Query('SELECT * FROM User LIMIT 1')
  Stream<User> getUser();

  @Query('SELECT * FROM User LIMIT 1')
  Future<User> getUserFuture();

  @insert
  Future<void> insertUser(User user);

  @update
  Future<int> updateUser(User user);

  @delete
  Future<void> deleteUser(User user);

  @Query('DELETE FROM User')
  Future<void> deleteAllUsers(); // query without returning an entity
}
```

Comment: Are `getUserInformationStream` and `getUser` defined in separate files?  If so, are you sure that the `User` and `Stream` classes are the same for both?

Comment: @jamesdlin i update post, `getUserInformationStream` is simple method to get data from `getUser` method on `user_dao.dart` class, `user_dao` class pasted into post, that means `getUserInformationStream` is `db_model.class` and `getUser` is in `user_dao.dart`

Comment: Check if the `import` statements in your files are exactly the same. Meaning that if one file has an `import` with a relative file path (like `import "../file.dart"`) all of them must use the same import syntax for the file.dart. (same for `import "package:..."`)